# Передача параметров в jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Есть файл jsp поставляется в библиотеке, менять не могу, но мне нужно передать параметр в этот jsp. Gри передаче тегом param переменная text появляется только в namespace param. Как я могу подставить в саму переменную text?

```
<jsp:include page="text.jsp"  >
        <jsp:param name="text" value="other" />
    </jsp:include>
```

сам text.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<h1> <c:out value="${text}"/></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно её предварительно установить

```
<c:set var="text" value="Hello"/>
<jsp:include page="text.jsp"/>
```